# In a batch file, is it possible to replace this use of SED and TR with a for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd

the batch file:

```
@echo.
@set curdrive=%~d0
@path | %curdrive%\utils\sed -e "s/PATH=//" | %curdrive%\utils\tr ; \n
@echo.
```

Sample output (one path element on each line):

```
C:\cheeso\bin
C:\Perl\bin
c:\utils
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\
c:\.net3.5
c:\.net2.0
c:\vs2008\common7\IDE
c:\netsdk2.0\bin
```

This batch file depends on the sed.exe and the tr.exe from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).
I'd like to do the same thing using only built-in commands and programs that are included with Windows.  Can I do it?  Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal
SET _Path="%Path:;=";"%"
FOR %%a IN (%_Path%) DO ECHO     %%~a
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning, abuse of recursion ahead:

```
@echo off

call :one "%PATH%"
goto :eof

:one
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%i in (%1) do (
    echo %%i
    if not "%%j"=="" call :one "%%j"
)
```

Comment: User "Jay" has a great alternative here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817280/how-does-for-work-in-cmd-batch-file/1293667#1293667

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-recursive version. Not really better, but I felt like looking for another solution:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
:again
FOR /F "delims=;" %%I IN ("%PATH%") DO ECHO %%I & SET PATH=!PATH:%%I;=!
IF DEFINED PATH GOTO :again
ENDLOCAL
```

I believe that this will only work for Windows XP, 2003 Server, and newer.

Comment: Did you try running this?  It just prints the first value in an infinite loop.  The "for" loop does not re-evaluate the expression in parens.

Comment: @Adam - yes, it works fine on Windows 2003. You are correct in that the `FOR` loop outputs the first item. Then it removes the item from `PATH`. The `IF DEFINED` is executed whenever the path is not empty. Be careful when typing the `SET` statement.

Comment: Much better than the UnxUtils version, and I like it better than the recursive evrsion, too.  But it didn't work for me, until I appended a final terminating ; to the path.

Comment: I copied your script exactly into a cmd file and ran it on my machine (Vista).  It didn't work.  Try an example where %PATH% doesn't end in ;.  I was mistaken before, it's repeating the last element, not the first (happened to be the same on my system).

Answer (score 0):

I started to use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set tpath=%path%;
echo.
:again
FOR /F "delims=;" %%I IN ("%TPATH%") DO (
  echo    %%I 
  set TPATH=!TPATH:%%I;=!
)
IF DEFINED TPATH GOTO :again

ENDLOCAL
```

But then decided this was simpler:

```
setlocal
set _path="%PATH:;=" "%"
for %%p in (%_path%) do if not "%%~p"=="" echo     %%~p
endlocal
```

Comment: Credit where credit is due.  The simpler one is the example from Jay here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817280/how-does-for-work-in-cmd-batch-file/1293667#1293667

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my Windows 2003 server and it worked. Here is the contents of my showpath.cmd:

```
@echo off
for %%p in (%PATH%) do echo %%p
```

Comment: That doesn't work for my path, because my path includes directory names that contain spaces.  So "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools\" gets displayed on 8 lines.