# How would you write a .bat or .cmd file to remove an element from the PATH?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd

Related:
[How to list the elements of the path in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424558)
[How does FOR work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817280/how-does-for-work-in-cmd-batch-file/1293667#1293667)

How would you write a batch file or CMD file to remove an element from the path?  It should handle gracefully:

- differences in case
- shortnames and long names

I've done this using tr.exe but it's slow and complicated and uses temporary files, which makes it even more complicated.

I *think* the answer is something like this:

```
setlocal
set tpath="" 
set _path="%PATH:;=" "%"
for %%p in (%_path%) do (
   call :KeepIfNotEqual %%p %elementToRemove% 
)
endlocal & set path=%tpath%
```

...where %elementToRemove% is the path element to remove.  KeepIfUnique would have to be a subroutine that takes two arguments - directory names, normalizes them, and appends the first argument to tpath if it is *not equal* to the 2nd argument (elementToRemove).

As I said, I can do this with tr.exe, but can I do it with just built-in commands in the windows cmd.exe shell?

**EDIT**: I guess when you get right down to it, the question is, how to do case-conversion in cmd.exe?

Comment: Windows 7 includes PowerShell 2, which will hopefully make your life much easier...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with, using Igor's hint.

```
@echo off
goto START

-------------------------------------------------------
 rmpath.bat

 remove a path element from path 

 Created Tue Sep 15 21:33:54 2009 

-------------------------------------------------------

:START
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

@REM require one argument (the path element to remove)
if  _%1==_ goto USAGE

@REM  ~fs = remove quotes, full path, short names
set fqElement=%~fs1

@REM convert path to a list of quote-delimited strings, separated by spaces
set fpath="%PATH:;=" "%"

@REM iterate through those path elements
for %%p in (%fpath%) do (
    @REM  ~fs = remove quotes, full path, short names
    set p2=%%~fsp
    @REM is this element NOT the one we want to remove?
    if /i NOT "!p2!"=="%fqElement%" (
        if _!tpath!==_ (set tpath=%%~p) else (set tpath=!tpath!;%%~p)
    )
)

set path=!tpath!

@call :LISTPATH

goto ALL_DONE
-------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------
:LISTPATH
  echo.
  set _path="%PATH:;=" "%"
  for %%p in (%_path%) do if not "%%~p"=="" echo     %%~p
  echo.
  goto :EOF
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
:USAGE
  echo usage:   rmpath ^<arg^>
  echo     removes a path element from the path.
  goto ALL_DONE

--------------------------------------------

:ALL_DONE
ENDLOCAL & set path=%tpath%
```

Comment: Great solution. Does this parameter need to be quoted? And does this remove ALL entries from the path, or just the first?

Answer (score 1):

`if` command has ignore case option

```
if /I "Blah"=="blah" (echo true) else (echo false)
```

See `if /?` for more help on using it. I generally found these commands helpful in determining how to do some cmd line trickery:

```
if /?
call /?
for /?
set /?
```

Comment: While I understand you don't want to spoon feed people answers, this question is not entirely simple, and has lots of moving parts. It's a common issue that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to Cheeso's answer... but I don't have enough rep to add a comment.

If you want the script he provided to work ***even after*** the batch file is finished, then change the last line like this this:

```
@echo off
  . . .
  . . .
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  . . .
  . . .
endlocal & set path=%tpath%
```

This employs a neat trick: the 'tpath' variable is available when that line is read-in and parsed by cmd.exe ***and expanded*** prior to getting deleted by 'endlocal'.

This allows the changes to the 'PATH' variable to persist even after the batch file exits.