# How to understand the expression "%PATH:;= %" in the batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I read [How does "FOR" work in cmd batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817280/how-does-for-work-in-cmd-batch-file) , there is an expression "%PATH:;= %",I can't understand,how the for batch gets the every paths set.How to understand the expression "%PATH:;= %" in the batch.This expression is what kind of features in the windows batch.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "%PATH:;= %" Means to replace all instances of ; in the environment variable %Path% with spaces

Answer (score 1):

this produces a result with replaced  `;` in %PATH% variable with spaces... 
here's the part of `set /?` that explains it:

```
Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:

    %PATH:str1=str2%
```