# How can I read some lines of windows command line in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Assume I use `dir` commend and it returns:

```
02/23/2014  03:03 PM    <DIR>          ManageEngine
09/28/2013  02:09 PM    <DIR>          opt
04/30/2014  09:30 AM    <DIR>          Oracle
09/29/2014  12:53 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
09/15/2014  12:59 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
09/30/2014  01:10 PM    <DIR>          ProgramData
08/10/2014  03:06 PM    <DIR>          Virtual Machines
05/05/2013  12:19 PM    <DIR>          wis
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  35,379,425,280 bytes free
```

Now I want to read the second line for example from the previous command line results(`dir`) and use it in my current command line.

Example:

```
del opt
```

How can I read the second line?

Comment: del opt would be useless, since opt is a dir.

Answer (score 0):

You use `for`. See [How does “FOR” work in cmd batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817280/how-does-for-work-in-cmd-batch-file). But you shouldn't be parsing the output of `dir`, you can use, again, [`for`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) to iterate directories:

> Directories only
>
> If set contains wildcards (* and ?), the specified command executes for each directory (instead of a set of files in a specified directory) that matches set. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> for /D {%% | %}variable in (set) do command [CommandLineOptions]
> ```

I'm not going to show how to get the *second* item in a set since that is a) trivial and b) wrong. Set ranking is random in lack of an order.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

rem use skip=n-1 where n is the line you want
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%# in ('dir') do (
    echo %%#
    rem delete echo to activate deletion
    echo rd /s /q "%%#"
    goto :break_for
)
:break_for
```

if you want to filter the line that contains `opt`

```
@echo off


for /f "delims=" %%# in ('dir^|find /i "opt"') do (
    echo %%#
)
```